# Python: Get unique tuples such that elements across all tuples are disjoint

Tags: python, list, pandas, set, tuples

There's a list of tuples:

```
all_tups = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (6, 8), (6, 7), (7, 9)]
```

What I wish to do:
Get the tuples such that if in any tuple, an element has appeared, then any other tuple with this element should be discarded (regardless of the position of element in any tuple).

So, there are several desired outputs possible:

```
[(1,2) (3,4) (6,8) (7,9)] OR
[(2,1) (4,3) (6,8) (7,9)]
```

and so on.

Originally, the first element of each tuple comes from one column of a Pandas dataframe and the second element of each tuple comes from another column of the same dataframe.

`C1  C2
0   1   2
1   2   1
2   3   4
3   3   5
4   4   3
5   6   8
6   6   7
7   7   9`

In the actual problem, there are millions of rows in the dataframe. Therefore, I am NOT looking for a for-loop based solution. Any approach that works on the dataframe or millions of tuples is fine except for a for-loop based solution.

What I have tried so far:
I have been able to obtain list of unique tuples using frozen sets:

```
uniq_tups = {frozenset(k) for k in all_tups}
```

(admittedly using list comprehensions which I would ideally also like to avoid). This gives me:

```
{frozenset({1, 2}),
 frozenset({6, 7}),
 frozenset({3, 5}),
 frozenset({3, 4}),
 frozenset({6, 8}),
 frozenset({7, 9})}
```

I can't seem to get a non-for loop way of making progress with this solution, or use any other approach that avoids looping.

I'm currently using Python 3.5, but have no issues using a Python 2.7 solution as well.

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: What's the purpose of the frozen sets here? Why not just use the tuples directly?

Comment: This was more of a shot in the dark for getting unique tuples, but still doesn't give the output I desire.

Comment: My point is that you could have just done `{tup for tup in all_tups}`

Comment: That would not remove duplicate tuples (without the consideration of order of appearance of elements). Frozen sets do that. The following is the output using your suggestion:
    {(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 9)}

Comment: Aha, I see now.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid for loop so much when actualy the list comprehensions are using them? I have a solution for your problem with generator function, but there is a need for a `for` loop. No idea why you are trying to avoid a loop when there is a need for one.

Comment: But using frozen sets allows `{3, 5}` and `{3, 4}` to both be present in the output, and I thought you want to avoid that.

Comment: @Nf4r: Of course _some_ kind of looping is unavoidable. However, if the looping can be done by Pandas or Numpy it will get done at the speed of compiled code which will be a _lot_ faster than any loops running at Python speed.

Comment: @PM2Ring: You are right, which is why the solution with frozensets is incomplete.

Comment: How come `(7, 9)` is in the expected output? Shouldn't it be rejected because `(6, 7)` precedes it? Or is `(7, 9)` allowed because  `(6, 7)` is ejected (due to the 6 being present in `(6, 8)`), so its elements aren't considered in the rejection process?

Comment: Well, you need to look at each element at least once (which will be a for loop in disguise any way you code it). You could then in parallel maintain a dictionary with all numbers that you've already got mapped to True, and your keep list. This would mean you'd cut down on the number of computations when looking to see if you've already got a tuple with that number.

Comment: @Aidenhjj A set is more compact than a dict with all the values set to `True`. FWIW, a Python set is essentially a dict with keys but no values.

Comment: Ok I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reasonably efficient way to do this in plain Python. We use a function `not_seen` to test if a tuple contains elements that have already been seen in an accepted tuple.

```
all_tups = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (6, 8), (6, 7), (7, 9)]

def not_seen(t, seen=set()):
    if t[0] in seen or t[1] in seen:
        return False
    seen.update(t)
    return True

unique = list(filter(not_seen, all_tups))
print(unique)
```

**output**

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 8), (7, 9)]
```

There's a slight problem with `not_seen`: it uses a default mutable argument `seen` to cache the seen elements, and that set cannot be cleared, so if you need to perform this operation again `seen` will still hold the old elements. We *could* make `seen` a global instead, but that would run slower. Another option is to use a factory function to produce a clean version of `seen` each time we need one. Eg:

```
def make_checker():
    def not_seen(t, seen=set()):
        if t[0] in seen or t[1] in seen:
            return False
        seen.update(t)
        return True
    return not_seen

not_seen = make_checker()
```

FWIW, here's a compact version of `not_seen`; it should be *almost* as efficient as the original, I'd be surprised if it's actually faster. :)

```
def not_seen(t, seen=set()):
    return False if t[0] in seen or t[1] in seen else seen.update(t) or True
```

We can convert that compact version into a lambda, and then we don't have to worry about the problem of clearing the `seen` set.

```
all_tups = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (6, 8), (6, 7), (7, 9)]

unique = list(filter(lambda t, seen=set():
    False if t[0] in seen or t[1] in seen else seen.update(t) or True, all_tups))
print(unique)
```

---

Here is a Numpy implementation. First we convert the data to a 2D Numpy array. Then we use `not_seen` with `numpy.apply_along_axis` to create a Numpy boolean array denoting pairs that should be accepted, and then use that boolean array to select the desired pairs.

```
import numpy as np

def not_seen(t, seen=set()):
    if t[0] in seen or t[1] in seen:
        return False
    seen.update(t)
    return True

all_tups = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (6, 8), (6, 7), (7, 9)]

all_tups = np.array(all_tups)
print(all_tups, all_tups.dtype)
print('- ' * 20)

filtered = all_tups[np.apply_along_axis(not_seen, 1, all_tups)]
print(filtered)
```

**output**

```
[[1 2]
 [2 1]
 [3 4]
 [3 5]
 [4 3]
 [6 8]
 [6 7]
 [7 9]] int32
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [6 8]
 [7 9]]
```

This *should* be faster than the plain Python implementation above. The looping process itself should be faster, the bottleneck is that we're still calling `not_seen` which is a plain Python function. Also, it uses more RAM because it has to construct the boolean array.

---

**Update**

It *is* actually possible to clear the `seen` set from outside the `not_seen` function. We can access a function's default arguments via its `.__default__` attribute (or `.func_defaults` in old versions of Python 2; `.__default__` works in Python 2.6, but not in 2.5).

Eg,

```
not_seen.__defaults__[0].clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do no think it is possible to avoid for-loops or list comprehensions. You are comparing elements which each other so somehow you must loop over them. If you want to avoid for-loops or list comprehensions because of memory usage then you might be interested in iterators or generators, something like `irange` or `xrange` will save you (huge amounts of) memory.

((*the more theoretical explanation of this issue*: it is about time and space complexity. This problem is likely to have time complexity *O*(*n*) or worse. But for space (= memory) complexity you have a good change to avoid *O*(*n*) and have something like *O*(1) or *O*(log *n*). ))

Do not know about the Panda side of your story. I have not enough experience with that package.

Comment: Python 3 `range` == Python 2 `xrange`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to avoid the for loops, while in the same time you are using them in your example solution, but a simple (I think) function to produce your output would be:

```
all_tups = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (6, 8), (6, 7), (7, 9)]
def tup_gen(tuple_list):
    s = set()
    for element in tuple_list:
        if s.intersection(element):
            continue
        yield element
        s.update(element)
```

It would be lazy, producing one tuple at a time (which would allow you to work on a big data sets), and the output would be:

```
result = list(tup_gen(all_tups))
print(result)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 8), (7, 9)]
```

Of course this is the way of doing it without using any specific library. I'm pretty sure that there must be something faster (even directly in PF), but I'm not into PF so much yet to give you an answer.

Comment: `s.intersection(element)` is a little more efficient than `s & set(element)` since it skips the explicit conversion of `element` to a set, but neither is great since they both have to create the resulting intersection set on every loop iteration.

Comment: Edited. And yes, I don't know how really deep you want to dig with the optimization, but if you need it to go to the bottom, for certain you will need to find some kind of library solution written probably in C-like language. Gonna go and try to do some research, and maybe will be able to give you an answer later.